# Check if static property exists on the class?

Tags: c++, c++20

How can i check, that some class, passed as a template argument, have some static property on it? Like `::size`

```cpp
  template<class Header>
  class Reader {
// e.g.  Header::size
  };
```

My concept is that each `Header` class must implement a `size` property that will be read by the `Reader` class. The Reader class, in turn, will read the number (`size`) of bytes from the file, and then pass the buffer to the `Header` ctor.

Comment: for what reason you want to check it?

Comment: @appleapple because this is my concept, each Header class must implement this property, which will tell header size to the reader. Reader will read `::size` bytes from a file and then pass buffer to the Header ctor

Comment: Are you trying to distinguish whether it exists or not? or do you want it to always exist? Templates are evaluated at compile time so if you use the template and you don't have `::size` it won't compile.

Comment: @mascoj check if it exist at compile time

Comment: since you add tag `c++20` you can simply use concept https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints. But really it would simply not compile even if you do nothing as @mascoj said

Comment: if it must be implemented and must the the constant value the easiest way is just to define `static const size_t header_size = Header::size;` and you will get compilation error if it is not defined or defined incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use a [concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints):

```
template <class T>
concept HasSize = requires(T) {
    T::size;
};

template <HasSize Header>
struct Reader {
    // Use Header::size
};
```